# Best way to store rows/columns from sheets/tables?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a workbook that fetches data from several other worksheets. Usually, the data is stored in a table in each sheet. In this case, one table is a data connection to our database where our orders are stored.

In order to successfully get the correct data from each sheet, I create a 'Data' sub that looks something like this:

```
Dim Wb(1 To 10) As Workbook
Dim Sh(1 To 10) As Worksheet
Dim Lo(1 To 10) As ListObject
Dim Ii&(1 To 10), Jj&(1 To 10), Kk&(1 To 10)

Sub Data()
    Set Wb(1) = ThisWorkbook
    Set Sh(1) = Wb(1).Worksheets("Input")
    Set Lo(1) = Sh(1).ListObjects("Input")
    With Lo(1)
        Ii(1) = .ListColumns("Date").Range.Column
        Ii(2) = .ListColumns("ArtNo").Range.Column
        Ii(3) = .ListColumns("ArtName").Range.Column
        Ii(4) = .ListColumns("ArtUnits").Range.Column ' Units in the article
        Ii(5) = .ListColumns("ArtLitres").Range.Column ' Litres in the article
        Ii(6) = .ListColumns("Quantity").Range.Column
        Ii(7) = .ListColumns("SumUnits").Range.Columne ' Units * Quantity
        Ii(8) = .ListColumns("SumLitres").Range.Columne ' Litres * Quantity
    End With

    ' Table from Database containing the orders
    Set Sh(2) = Wb(1).Worksheets("Orders")
    Set Lo(2) = Sh(2).ListObjects("Orders")
    With Lo(2)
        Jj(1) = .ListColumns("Date").Range.Column
        Jj(2) = .ListColumns("ArtNo").Range.Column
        Jj(6) = .ListColumns("Quantity").Range.Column
    End With

    ' Database containing detailed information on the articles
    Set Sh(3) = Wb(1).Worksheets("ArtData")
    Set Lo(3) = Sh(3).ListObjects("ArtData")
    With Lo(3)
        Kk(2) = .ListColumns("ArtNo").Range.Column
        Kk(3) = .ListColumns("ArtName").Range.Column
        Kk(4) = .ListColumns("ArtUnits").Range.Column ' Units in the article
        Kk(5) = .ListColumns("ArtLitres").Range.Column ' Litres in the article
    End With
End Sub
```

So, when I've run the Data sub, I know where all the relevant columns are. And I have seen to it that each number represents the same column name. By that I mean that Ii(2), Jj(2) and Kk(2) all equal the column named "ArtNo" in each table.

I started using arrays because they are quicker to declare. Instead of declaring separate integers, like "ArtNo1", "ArtNo2", "ArtNo3" or ArtNo(1 to 3), I'd simply know that the digit (1) equals ArtNo in each table, and I'd use one Array ("Ii", "Jj", "Kk") per table. I will only have to know what each digit represents and worst case; I would scroll up to the Data sub and get the answer there.

**In order to get data I'd do something like this:**

```
Sub TransferData()
Dim dDate As Date
Dim Str$
Dim Cel As Range
Dim X&, Y&
    CalcOff
    Data
    Wb(1).RefreshAll ' Updates the Order data connection
    X = Lo(1).DataBodyRange.Row ' Get input row for the data
    Str = Format(dDate, "yyyy-mm-dd", vbMonday, vbFirstFourDays) ' Used for filtering the table

    ' Filtering the order database, showing only the chosen date
    Lo(2).AutoFilter.ShowAllData
    Lo(2).Range.AutoFilter Field:=Jj(1), Operator:=xlFilterValues, Criteria2:=Array(2, Str)

    With Sh(1)
        For Each Cel In Lo(2).ListColumns(Jj(2)).DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

            ' Transferring from the Order database
            .Cells(X, Ii(1)) = dDate
            .Cells(X, Ii(2)) = Cel
            .Cells(X, Ii(6)) = Sh(2).Cells(Cel.Row, Jj(6))

            ' Find the 'ArtNo' row from the Info database
            Y = Lo(3).ListColumns(Kk(2)).Find(Cel, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole).Row

            ' Transferring from the Info database
            .Cells(X, Ii(3)) = Sh(3).Cells(Y, Kk(3))
            .Cells(X, Ii(4)) = Sh(3).Cells(Y, Kk(4))
            .Cells(X, Ii(5)) = Sh(3).Cells(Y, Kk(5))

            ' Calculating units and litres
            .Cells(X, Ii(7)) = .Cells(X, Ii(6)) * .Cells(X, Ii(4))
            .Cells(X, Ii(8)) = .Cells(X, Ii(6)) * .Cells(X, Ii(5))

            X = X + 1
        Next Cel
    End With
    CalcOn
    End
End Sub

Function CalcOff()
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
End Function

Function CalcOn()
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Function
```

**My question is:**

Is there an easier way to transfer data like this? I'm thinking classes, but I have never worked with them so I'd really appreciate if someone could give an example of how to implement classes while doing a transfer like this one.

*Please note that the code is just a quickly written example. I've placed all tables at "A1" in each sheet, otherwise I would have to do the following for each column:*

```
Ii(1) = .ListColumns("Date").Range.Column - .Range.Column + 1
```

Comment: Do you know about Power Query? It can combine data from different sources, Excel sheets, tables, external data bases, and more. You can massage the data, clean it, create calculated columns and all sorts of things. Maybe that would be an alternative to doing all that with VBA.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Short answer; We have to use Excel and that's why I have to use VBA. Sad but true.

Comment: Power Query is an add-in for Excel. By Microsoft.

Comment: Sorry for sounding stupid. All I know about Power Query is that it is a COM Add-In and it isn't installed on our computers. Since I don't have admin rights, I can't use it since it can't be installed.

Comment: I hear you. Power Query is the best thing that has happened to Excel in the last 5 years. The installation barrier can be tackled by convincing your boss that it will make you so much more productive. (I know, I know)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. **Use Microsoft Query**. It does not require installation of PowerQuery as it is available just like your database link natively from Excel. Below example of transfering data between Worksheets:

```
SELECT * FROM [Input$] as I INNER JOIN [AnotherWorksheet$] as A ON I.ArtNo = A.ArtNo
```

Then update the Query from VBA:

```
ActiveSheet.QueryTables(1).Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
```

You can create a Microsoft Query from the Data ribbon tab (From Other Sources) or using my Add-In (just for creating the query): [link](http://www.analystcave.com/excel-tools/excel-sql-add-in-free/).

**Here an example of how to use Iif to return different values based on a day of the week:**

```
SELECT Iif( DatePart ("w", #05/07/2015#,2) = 1, 1,0) as StartMonday,
Iif( DatePart ("w", #05/07/2015#,2) = 2, 1,0) as StartTuesday, 
Iif( DatePart ("w", #05/07/2015#,2) = 3, 1,0) as StartWednesday,
Iif( DatePart ("w", #05/07/2015#,2) = 4, 1,0) as StartThursday,    
Iif( DatePart ("w", #05/07/2015#,2) = 5, 1,0) as StartFriday
```

This will return something like:

```
StartMonday | StartTuesday | StartWednesday | StartThursday | StartFriday
0           | 0            | 0              | 1             | 0
```

Comment: Good input. However, there are several columns that need to be created (that don't exist in the tables mentioned). So these will have to be created by code anyways. That's why I'm simply looking for an easier way to control all data. And that's why I'm thinking that maybe a collection or a class could work, but I'm still looking for an example of how that should be setup.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean that these columns need to be created. The SQL query can create new columns. New columns can be calculations, formulas, or simply the result of other columns in the referenced tables. The result of an SQL query is a header of columns and the rows - you can manipulate the columns as you like.

Comment: Did not know you could create new columns. Is it also possible to make a case that uses a date to pick a certain column?

Example: 7 columns named "Start monday", "Start tuesday" etc. If the date I have provided is a monday, I want to pick the column "Start monday". 

Is that case possible to implement in an SQL query?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Sidenote: Your script can't be downloaded, it simply says "No file attached yet".

Comment: No problem. Thanks for the heads up! Fixed the issue. You can download the AddIn if needed.